# find available object methods in VBScript-derivative language

Tags: object, methods, vbscript

how do i find out the available methods of an object in VBScript? i'm dealing with a CAD program that uses a scripting language based on VBscript but it doesn't have an object browser. i'm trying to script a 3rd party plugin and the developers are being reticent.  thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript is not able to give you an overview of available methods for an object. Also the other way around it is not possible to do a kind of `HasMethod` on an object. So you need to get your information elsewhere.

My first try would be to find documentation from the internet because with some luck you get also a good description and some examples about what the methods are doing.
Secondary you could try to load the object library as a reference in VBA for an MS Office application (Word, Excel etc.). Then you can peek the methods as soon as you create a variable as that object or use the object browser of VBA.
(Assuming you do not have access to Visual Studio. When you have access to it, it would be even easier to use VS.)

Comment: And you can add watches in VBA, too.